# Stopped supremum of the Brownian local time still $L^p$ bounded in space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and $L_t^x$ its local time in $x$ at time $t$. For fixed $t$ and $p>1$, it holds that
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \operatorname{E} [ (L_t^x)^p ] < \infty,$$
which can for example be proven by
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \operatorname{E} [ (L_t^x)^p ] \leq \operatorname{E} [ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (L_t^x)^p] \leq C_p \, \operatorname{E} [ \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |B_t|^p ] \leq C_p \operatorname{E} [ \langle B,B \rangle_t^{p/2} ] = C_p t^{p/2},$$
where $C_p$ is a positive constant which changes between inequalities. A proof for the second inequality (which also holds for $t=\infty$) can be found in "(Semi-)Martingale Inequalities and Local Times" by Barlow/Yor from the eighties, the third inequality is Burkholder-Davis-Gundy.

**My first question:** Am I correct in assuming that one can replace $t$ by a $L^1$-bounded stopping time and the supremum remains finite? In the proof above, the first inequality stays valid, the second and third should follow from stopping but I don't know how to bound $\operatorname{E} [\langle B_{\tau},B_{\tau} \rangle^{p/2}]$.

**My second question:** 
Does it still hold that the supremum is finite 
if $\tau$ is just assumed to be almost surely finite?

Comment: Regarding your first question: Since $\langle B_{\tau},B_{\tau}\rangle = \tau$, the stopping time has to satisfy $\tau \in L^{p/2}$. Obviously, this is true for any bounded stopping time.

Comment: @saz What I meant was $L^1$-bounded stopping time, but your argument stays true nonetheless. My problem was exactly how to prove that $\langle B_{\tau},B_{\tau} \rangle = \tau$, but I think I got it now. As $B_{t \land \tau}$ is still a martingale, one can show that $\langle B_{\cdot \land \tau}, B_{\cdot \land \tau} \rangle_t = \langle B, B \rangle_{t \land \tau} = t \land \tau$. Then you let $t \to \infty$, correct?

Comment: Exactly, that's it.